# How to keep cursor horizontal position while scrolling in Vim

Tags: vim

This question looks like [How to keep cursor horizontal position while scrolling in VIM?](https://superuser.com/questions/301253/how-to-keep-cursor-horizontal-position-while-scrolling-in-vim) but it's actually not.

Vim always tries to snap the cursor to the first non-whitespace character of the destination line while scrolling.

Consider this text:

```
A
    Line 2
```

Now the cursor points to 'A', when I press `<C-d>` to scroll a half page, Vim will automatically snap the cursor to 'L' in the second line.

What I want is to remain the horizontal position of cursor unless I explicitly command Vim to do so (like 'h', 'l').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option you want is `'startofline'`. Specifically, you want to turn it off since it is on by default:

```
:set nostartofline
```

See:

```
:help 'startofline'
```

(with the single quotes as part of the help command)